# Getting Youtube Title given an id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, youtube

I found a great reference for getting the youtube video title given a Youtube video id but I am unsure how to return the title in functions that he gives.In the videoInfoCallback function  i have it returning message but I am not sure what is being passed into the info parameter. Any suggestions. Here is the resource that I am using: [Parser](http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2011/11/youtube-retrieving-video-information-in-javascript)

Here is the code that I am playing around with:

```
function registerScript(url) {
            var s = document.createElement('script');
            s.type = 'text/javascript';
            s.src = url;
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
        }

        function videoInfoCallback(info) {
            if (info.error) {
                alert('Error\n\n' + info.error.message);
            } else {
                var message = info.data.title;
                return message;
            }
            return "hello";
        }


        function getVideoInformation(id) {
            if (id) {
                return registerScript('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + id + '?v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=videoInfoCallback');
            } else {
                alert('Please enter an id.');
            }
        }
```

Basically, I want to have a function that takes in a Youtube video id like this CFF0mV24WCY and have it return the title.

Comment: You can use the debugger in your browser and set a breakpoint in your callback function to view what `info` contains.

Comment: Ok, I know what the contents are but it is just an object that contains all the video information. What is the this doing ?v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=videoInfoCallback'?

Comment: They are query parameters to the YouTube API documented [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters). `v` is the version of the API, `alt` is the format in which your data is returned, and `callback` is the callback function that is fired once data is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not really answering your above question but it may help you in ur quest

Its just a simple youtube search that brings in the title video and view count

html

```
<input type="text" id="Search"  /><br/>
<input id="show" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="Show();"/>

<div id="result">

</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#show").click(function () {
        getYoutube($("#Search").val() + "Offical Film Trailer");
    });
});

function getYoutube(title) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: yt_url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=' + title + '&format=5&max-results=1&v=2&alt=jsonc',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.data.items) {
                $.each(response.data.items, function (i, data) {
                    var video_id = data.id;
                    var video_title = data.title;
                    var video_viewCount = data.viewCount;
                    var video_frame = "<iframe width='600' height='385' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video_id + "' frameborder='0' type='text/html'></iframe>";
                    var final_res = "<div id='title'>" + video_title + "</div><div>" + video_frame + "</div><div id='count'>" + video_viewCount + " Views</div>";
                    $("#result").html(final_res);
                });


            } else {
                $("#result").html("<div id='no'>No Video</div>");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `final` is `reserved keyword` don't use it as variable name. I have changed it to `final_res`.